# Ruby on rails - user is nil after creating a session and redirecting home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a rails app.

- I am using devise to handle authentication
- If the user is an admin, he or she should be able to see a link in the navbar that redirects to the whole list of profiles (for testing purposes)

```
    <% if !user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete,  class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <% if !@user.nil? && @user.admin? %>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "See all profiles", profiles_path, class: "nav-link" %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "My profile", user_profile_path(current_user, current_user.user_profile), class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
```

- However, said link only shows after going inside the `my profile` link. I did a raise in the UserProfiles controller to see what's going on and apparently the `user` is nil in the homepage even after logging in, hence the reason why the see all profiles link is not appearing
- My guess is that I am missing an instance variable that provides the user id somewhere, (pages controller perhaps?) I don't have a users controller or user sessions controller yet. Basically, I don't understand why is the user nil after logging in and why is the log out link showing up without a user?

UserProfiles controller

```
class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show]
  
  def index
    @user_profiles = UserProfile.all
  end

  def show
    @user_profile = UserProfile.find(params[:id])
    @user_profile.user = @user
  end
  
  private
  
  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you check `!user_signed_in?` -> not singed in, that your problem, it should be ` if user_signed_in?`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The ```!user_signed_in?``` is to shot the log in and sign up links. The logic for a signed in user comes after the else. The problem is that when I go back to home, the ```see all profiles``` dissapears cause there is no user.

Comment: i think i know your problem now, your erb file above belongs to HomeControlle not UserProfilesController, right ? you should use `current_user` for both,  should not set `@user = current_user`, since @user on UserProfilesController will be nil on HomeController, meanwhile `current_user` will be set each controller after user signed-in.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, I was nesting the ```user_profile``` routes inside the user routes. As soon as I separated them, it all worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `@user` from the `controller` so cannot use in the `view`.

You should change your code to

```
<% if !@user_profile.user.nil? && @user_profile.user.admin? %>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <%= link_to "See all profiles", profiles_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, Kamal. Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it didn't work, I'm still getting nil. Neither the user nor the user_profile are available in the home view. I'll keep looking and let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: could you show the ```user model``` and ```user_profile model```?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, I was nesting the ```user_profile``` routes inside the user routes. As soon as I separated them, it all worked fine. Thanks for your help.