# After successful login Rails 5.2 Warden reports user is 'nil' and so will not load home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, devise, warden

I am running an upgraded system on `ubuntu 18.04` using `rails 5.2.8`, `ruby 2.5.1`, `devise 4.5.0` (problem occurs with any devise version > 4.5) and `warden 1.2.9`.

When I logon I get the following debug output:

```
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN SIGN-IN
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] DEBUG -- Warden::Manager.after_authentication: User USER@live.com has signed in.
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- ^^^^^^^^^ check_reference: request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = https://SERVER.com/d/users/sign_in  params[:controller] = users/sessions
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- ======================= SessionsController: format.html  current_user: #<User signed_in: true, id: 25, email: "USER@live.com", first_name: "FIRST", last_name: "LAST", role: "Administrator", auto_signout_enabled: true, password_changed: false, force_password_reset: false, updated_at: "2022-06-02 20:02:21", created_at: "2020-01-10 13:24:20">
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- ======================== application_controller: after_sign_in_path_for
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Redirected to http://LOCALAPP/
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- ======================= SessionsController: User USER@live.com signed-in from Web browser.
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Completed 302 Found in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-02 13:02:21 -0700
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Processing by RuntimeController#index as HTML
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] DEBUG -- Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch: User nil   opts: {:scope=>:user}
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2022-06-02 13:02:21] INFO -- Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch: User is nil? true   opts: {:scope=>:user}   auth: Warden::Proxy:20581780 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x0000000004d66b28>}
```

The debug indicates that the logon was successful (which is verified by the user table in the database).  The line that reads `Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch: User is nil...` is where the problem shows up.  In a system where everything is working properly, the following lines should look something like

```
[2022-06-02 16:14:36] INFO -- ********************************* RUNTIME VIEW *********************************
[2022-06-02 16:14:36] DEBUG -- [VIEWS HELPER] get_view_connectivity view_id: 15
<<continue to load home page >>
```

That is, the activity immediately following a logon is a redirect to the home page. However, in this case it fails because (I think) the user (current_user?) has become **nil** or in some other way invalidated, so we just stay on the logon page.  The nil user is detected in a warden callback as follows:

```
  Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch do |user, auth, opts|
    Rails.logger.debug("Warden::Manager.after_failed_fetch: User is nil? #{user.nil?}   opts: #{opts.inspect}   auth: #{auth.inspect}".default_warn)
  end
```

On the system where this was working we were running rails 5.0.1, ruby 2.3.3, devise 4.2.0 and warden 1.2.7.

I also tried installing warden 1.2.7 into the 5.2.8 environment, but there was no change.  The devise 4.2.0 gem requires **railties (< 5.1, >= 4.1.0)** so it won't work in the new environment.

I ran into this problem before and the only solution I could find at the time was to revert back to the old versions.  However, it is harder and harder to maintain systems with older versions of ruby gems.  Every time a new version of a gem, or an altogether new gem is added, I might spend hours playing rubygem whack-a-mole.

This problem is also similar to:
[Ruby on rails - user is nil after creating a session and redirecting home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527428/ruby-on-rails-user-is-nil-after-creating-a-session-and-redirecting-home)

Comment: Updated the world to: `ubuntu 20.04`, `rails 7.0.3`, `ruby 3.0.1`, `devise 4.8.1` and `warden 1.2.9`.  Same problem: can't fetch a user from the session after a successful login.  Suggestions?

Comment: Also note the `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`, which might suggest that even after a successful login the default route is inaccessible.  Suggestions?